# python pandas index.get_loc raising KeyError despite the key being present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

I need to get the row number of a specific Unix timestamp, or the row number of the closest Unix timestamp if there isn't an exact match. 
I tried the following:

```
x = df.loc[df['unixTime']==1506448028].index[0]
```

which worked for exact matches, but I couldn't find a way to set a tolerance or find the nearest value if there wasn't an exact match.

I also tried:

```
x = df.index.get_loc(1506448028, method='nearest', tolerance=10)
```

but it is raising a key error even though that exact key is in the dataframe.

Here is what the data looks like:

```
Out[89]: 
        unixTime        lat       long         alt
0     1506447200  39.129079 -84.511796  217.958542
1     1506447191  39.129079 -84.511796  217.958542
2     1506447200  39.129079 -84.511796  217.958542
3     1506447558  39.130221 -84.507324  217.958542
4     1506447558  39.130247 -84.507221  217.958542
5     1506447558  39.130260 -84.507169  217.958542
6     1506447558  39.130267 -84.507144  217.958542
7     1506447558  39.128953 -84.511676  215.973724
8     1506447567  39.128991 -84.511545  215.973724
9     1506447570  39.129015 -84.511679  221.638443
10    1506447576  39.128930 -84.511686  221.962585
11    1506447582  39.128912 -84.511712  222.543442
12    1506447588  39.129003 -84.511683  222.282623
13    1506447594  39.129002 -84.511696  225.494690
14    1506447600  39.128912 -84.511724  224.964630
15    1506447606  39.128991 -84.511683  224.597717
16    1506447612  39.128950 -84.511725  225.394653
17    1506447618  39.128953 -84.511740  226.599243
18    1506447624  39.128974 -84.511605  226.195770
19    1506447630  39.128950 -84.511646  225.726181
20    1506447636  39.128931 -84.511735  226.083969
21    1506447642  39.128931 -84.511727  225.133530
22    1506447648  39.128940 -84.511840  226.574783
23    1506447654  39.129015 -84.511668  226.336227
24    1506447660  39.129095 -84.511718  227.314056
25    1506447666  39.129106 -84.511818  227.421555
26    1506447672  39.129064 -84.511947  227.557953
27    1506447681  39.129021 -84.512115  227.557953
28    1506447683  39.128886 -84.512158  227.237656
29    1506447689  39.128941 -84.512043  227.278915
         ...        ...        ...         ...
4751  1506452685  39.129019 -84.511971  240.232147
4752  1506452689  39.128954 -84.511990  239.229721
4753  1506452696  39.129030 -84.511841  238.480148
4754  1506452699  39.129061 -84.511804  237.872940
4755  1506452699  39.129068 -84.511809  237.377457
4756  1506452702  39.129059 -84.511761  236.937805
4757  1506452708  39.129074 -84.511749  236.517029
4758  1506452714  39.129059 -84.511770  236.134262
4759  1506452720  39.129041 -84.511709  235.667023
4760  1506452726  39.128983 -84.511709  235.206390
4761  1506452732  39.128972 -84.511713  234.759903
4762  1506452732  39.128957 -84.511694  218.916260
4763  1506452733  39.128955 -84.511697  218.885803
4764  1506452734  39.128953 -84.511700  218.858765
4765  1506452735  39.128951 -84.511702  218.833496
4766  1506452736  39.128949 -84.511704  218.811340
4767  1506452737  39.128946 -84.511705  218.792725
4768  1506452738  39.128956 -84.511709  217.345093
4769  1506452739  39.128966 -84.511712  217.287170
4770  1506452740  39.128975 -84.511716  217.250488
4771  1506452741  39.128975 -84.511716  217.185913
4772  1506452742  39.128975 -84.511716  217.162598
4773  1506452743  39.128975 -84.511716  217.177856
4774  1506452744  39.128975 -84.511716  217.164185
4775  1506452745  39.128975 -84.511716  217.164169
4776  1506452746  39.128975 -84.511716  217.145004
4777  1506452747  39.128986 -84.511719  217.197449
4778  1506452748  39.128994 -84.511722  217.215179
4779  1506452749  39.129002 -84.511725  217.219131
4780  1506452750  39.129007 -84.511726  217.221527

[4781 rows x 4 columns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Series.idxmin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) method:

Demo:

```
In [264]: df
Out[264]:
        unixTime        lat       long         alt
0     1506447200  37.629079 -86.011796  216.458542
1     1506447191  37.629079 -86.011796  216.458542
2     1506447200  37.629079 -86.011796  216.458542
3     1506447558  37.630221 -86.007324  216.458542
4     1506447558  37.630247 -86.007221  216.458542
...          ...        ...        ...         ...
2994  1506450890  37.634599 -86.015575  197.862915
2995  1506450891  37.634595 -86.015585  198.044250
2996  1506450892  37.634594 -86.015596  199.779419
2997  1506450893  37.634596 -86.015602  199.778015
2998  1506450894  37.634598 -86.015608  199.778320

[2999 rows x 4 columns]

In [268]: (df['unixTime']-1506448028).abs().idxmin()
Out[268]: 311
```

check:

```
In [270]: df.loc[[311]]
Out[270]:
       unixTime        lat       long         alt
311  1506448028  37.630432 -86.016418  235.709106
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [273]: (df['unixTime']-1506450454).abs().idxmin()
Out[273]: 2723

In [274]: df.loc[[(df['unixTime']-1506450454).abs().idxmin()]]
Out[274]:
        unixTime        lat       long        alt
2723  1506450450  37.634045 -86.015777  218.11084
```

Comment: How did you format that? I tried pasting it with an 8 space indent but it just becomes one block of code..

Comment: @thymeandspace, select code, press `Ctrl+K` - that's it ;-)

Comment: Also, what if the timestamp = 1506450454? So there isn't an exact match. How can I find the row number corresponding to the closest timestamp?

Comment: @thymeandspace, glad i could help :)